# Android Emulator warning guest is not online - how to turn off new quick boot feature?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've had a very awful experience using the [emulator quick boot.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/quick-boot-top-features-in-android.html)

its suppose to allow the emulator to open under 6 seconds with state preserved. 
it is just constantly freezing or shows an error of "guest is not online". I'd rather just disable quickboot but i cant find an option for it.  Is there any adb command then that can be used to disable quick boot ?

I"ve tried with emulators running api 23, & 26 on mac high sierra with Hax 6.2.1

Comment: from developer docs,No additional setup is required because Quick Boot is enabled by default starting with Android Emulator v27.0.2.

Comment: share your pc configuration

Comment: In windows version "Boot option: Cold boot/Quick boot" is under "Advanced Settings" when creating or editing virtual device. You do not have such setting when using mac?

Comment: thanks your right, i found it.  exactly where you said it was if you need to make an answer you can.

Comment: check quick boot https://stackoverflow.com/a/48031415/2826147

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as pointed out in the comments there is now a quick boot option in the AVD Manager when editing/creating a emulator. I set mine to cold boot to disable Quick boot.

[image]

Comment: My android studio not showing boot option (https://imgur.com/a/CnzKZs7) but showing cold boot now here (https://imgur.com/a/pRJVWEi) , how to get these boot option in advance settings .Using Android Studio 3.2

Comment: its right infront of you. your just not scrollling down.  go back to the first image you showed here :imgur.com/a/CnzKZs7 . keep scrolling down with your mouse to reveal the options.