# Android emulator - Don't save state by default

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, boot, cold-start

In the latest update for Android studio, the emulator has started saving snapshots of the current state of the device by default and going back to that snapshot when reopened, which is not the behavior that I want. How can I **disable** that and go back to the previous behavior, **where it just closes and resets the emulator?**

[UI after hitting the X button to close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fl9Sm.jpg)

[image]

`Android Studio 3.0.1`, with Emulator version 27.0.2 and HAXM 6.2.1

Comment: i don't understand why we need to have this feature, cos it never worked for me. It cost a lot of time to save the state, then and cost a lot of time to initialize the state again (but mostly it will hang), and then I have to use the cool boot again

Comment: i5 7th gen, 1TB HDD, 128GB SSD, 2GB 1050GTX, 16GB ram and my entire computer freezes because of this. Wtf. Useless feature

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> disable that and go back to the previous behavior

**Unselect quick boot** as shown below

This is default behaviour from update of **Android Studio 3.0**

Please unselect quick boot if you don't want to save state and select cold boot

Check [quick boot emulator in details](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html)

> Steps
>
> 1> Choose device like phone - pixel 2
>
> 2> select your system image
>
> 3> Verify configuration - show advance setting - emulator performance
>   check cold boot to disable
>
> 4> Finish

[image]

OR

you can also change it from

> **Emulator --> More --> Settings --> Change quick-boot state --> Save**

[image]

Comment: You won't be able to find it in the Emulator > Settings anymore. Now this is located in Snapshots => Settings => Save quick-boot state on exit for AVD...

Answer (score 23):

**Updated** thanks to @James KO
Steps are very similar:

`...` (on the right panel) -> Snapshots tap -> Settings (top tab on detail view) -> `Auto-save current state to Quickboot` dropdown

[image: updated image]

**end update**

In the latest version of the Android Studio (I am running **3.1.2**), it is no longer in the AVD Manager settings. I found it under **Extended Controls** on emulator itself.

1. Start emulator
2. Click three dots (...) on emulator panel
   [image]
3. Go to Settings -> General, towards the bottom *"Save quick-boot state on exit for AVD:"*
   [image]

Comment: Since this post was written a few months ago, it's moved to yet another location. On the left-hand menu there is a new section called "Snapshots", click that and then click the "Settings" tab under that section to get to this option.

Comment: @JamesKo Could you post your comment as an answer to save poor people like me from scratching the head after reading all the now misleading answers?

Comment: @Hong I updated answer above with James Ko answer. Thank you James Ko

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it via command line:

```
emulator @avd_name -no-snapshot-save
```

[check details](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html)