# Android Studio Emulator isn't running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to build and run an android application on android studio. (I'm just testing it out, so I created an "Empty Activity" project.) When I build and run the application on the emulator, the emulator crashes with the following errors:

```
3/29/2018
10:43 PM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

10:43 PM    Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

10:43 PM    Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!

10:43 PM    Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!

10:43 PM    Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

10:43 PM    Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

10:43 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

10:43 PM    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

10:43 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

10:43 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

10:43 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

10:44 PM    Gradle build finished in 10s 924ms

10:44 PM    Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

10:44 PM    Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!

10:44 PM    Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!

10:44 PM    Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

10:44 PM    Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

10:44 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

10:44 PM    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

10:44 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

10:44 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

10:44 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I run the android app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48801118/8089770

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48031415/8089770

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio

Comment: @VishvaDave Thanks! I changed it to software, and now the emulator opens, stays open, but doesn't respond.

Comment: @VishvaDave Don't have the "Boot options".

Comment: Try creating other device like pixel.. first restart the studio and then create and run

Comment: @VishvaDave The emulator doesn't respond with following error `Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\simch\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_27.avd/userdata.img
Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
Emulator: Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)`

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=emulator%3A+ERROR%3A+Missing+initial+data+partition+file%3A+C%3A%5CUsers%5Csimch%5C.android%5Cavd%5CPixel_XL_API_27.avd%2Fuserdata.img+Emulator%3A+Warning%3A+Quick+Boot+%2F+Snapshots+not+supported+on+this+machine.+A+CPU+with+EPT+%2B+UG+features+is+currently+needed.+We+will+address+this+in+a+future+release.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=A969WsWWH6ry8AeVsaaQBQ