# Android avd emulator - how to save "Do you want to save the current state for the next quick boot?" in config.ini file

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device, qemu

When creating an avd, starting it for the first time and then trying to close the emulator, the user will be prompted with a dialog reading:

```
Do you want to save the current state for the next quick boot?

Note: Saving the snapshot may take longer because free RAM is low.
```

I would like to save this parameter, before starting the emulated device, within its `config.ini` file.

However I'm not clear on which option it is.

Things I tried:
Adding these lines to the `config.ini`

```
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile=
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot=no
fastboot.forceColdBoot=no
fastboot.forceFastBoot=yes
```

Creating an additional file within the `config.ini` directory of the avd called `quickbootChoice.ini` that simply reads:

```
saveOnExit = true
```

Non of which helped, on every first shutdown of the emulated device this dialog pops up...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: They decided to ask regardless of those settings if free ram is low https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/refs/heads/emu-master-dev/android/android-emu/android/skin/qt/tool-window.cpp#1125

Comment: @yjh0502 any idea how to resolve this? My CI won't progress due to this dialog

Answer (score 1):

According to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/refs/heads/emu-master-dev/android/android-emu/android/skin/qt/tool-window.cpp the popup does not appear if the method returns based on this:

```
if (saveOnExitChoice == SaveSnapshotOnExit::Always &&
    (fc::isEnabled(fc::QuickbootFileBacked) ||
     (!savesWereSlow && !hasLowRam))) {
    return true;
}
```

Setting `QuickbootFileBacked = on` in `.android/advancedFeatures.ini` fixed it for me. See https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/08/android-emulator-28.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting the emulator from the command line. Then provide the `-no-snapshot-save` parameter, to prevent it from saving.

```
emulator @Nexus_5X_API_23 -no-snapshot-save
```

reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this setting in Android Studio, see this answer for instructions: [Android emulator - Don't save state by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024506/android-emulator-dont-save-state-by-default)

Comment: I do not want to use Android Studio for this.
Imagine being on a CI Server and wanting to run emulator tests.