# How do I disable quick boot in Xamarin's new "Android Device Manager"?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I created a new virtual Android device and now face the *"Guest hasn't come online in 7 seconds"* problem. It appears to be a well-known problem and the solution seems to be to turn of "quick boot":

- [Android Studio guest hasnt come online in 7 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48010244/87698)
- [Android Emulator warning guest is not online - how to turn off new quick boot feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47978151/87698)

Unfortunately, the "AVD manager" mentioned in those Q&As has been deprecated, and while Microsoft [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/sdk-cli-tooling-changes) that Xamarin's Android Device Manager is *"functionally equivalent"* to the old AVD manager tool, I cannot find the option to disable quick boot there:

[image: Android Device Manager]

Where do I find this option in the new Android Device Manager?

Comment: This does not exist currently. If it's possible, please use the `Help -> Send Feedback -> Provide a Suggestion` to let us know about this. We are aware that many quickboot features are not editable/usable currently in the Device Manager. You can edit properties manually such as adding `fastboot.forceColdBoot=yes` and `fastboot.forceFastBoot=no`. However this should be more user-friendly with quick editing or right clicking the emulator and hitting `Launch as Cold Boot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick boot setting is in a different `ini`-based file than the one that Xamarin's AVD manager is editing:

```
quickbootChoice.ini
```

The only entry is boolean `saveOnExit`:

```
saveOnExit = false

saveOnExit = true
```

You can create the file yourself since Xamarin AVD manager is lacking the ability (it goes in the same AVD directory as the config.ini|hardware-qemu.ini|... files.

Or once your emulator is running, use the emulator's extended settings dialog to enable/disable it (thus creating/changing the `quickbootChoice.ini` file)

[image]